# How take state from store? angular/ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

i long time work with react/redux and now i trying to learn angular/ngrx.

And I had questions

how write in store? In redux store i just connect used function
        connect, and in angular i connect like this

```
        @Component({   selector: 'home',
            templateUrl: './home.html' }) export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

            console = console;
            todos$: Observable<any>;
            todo: string;
            todoDate: string;
            indexToEdit: number | null;


            constructor(private store: Store<any>) {}

            ngOnInit() {
                this.todos$ = this.store.select('todoReducer');
            }
```

next i use `todos$` for cycle in template, but if i `console.log(todos$)`
its just object of store, and i can't find my store state, how can I read state from the store?

Comment: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/README.md read the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rxjs operator [do](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do) to show sideeffects dont forget to import it.

```
this.todos$ = this.store.select('todoReducer').do(res => console.log(res))
```

another way will be to subscribe but this will defeat the purpose of ngrx. And you will not use async pipe in template and also you will need to unsubscribe.

```
storeSub: Subscription;

this.storeSub = this.store.select('todoReducer').subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data);
  this.todos = data;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

todo$ is an observable of your state.

You can use it in controller like this:

```
this.todo$.subscribe(state => console.log(state));
```

Or in your template like this:

```
{{ todo$ | async }}
<input type="text" name="myfield" (change)="modifyField($event.target.value)" [value]="(todo$ | async)?.myfield"></input>
```